# Facebook: webpage working as an app and a page

Tags: authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I want to make a webpage, that works as an APP (in facebook, iframe) and as a usual webpage too.
How can I accomplish this in a proper way?
Right now, I'm connecting to facebook as an APP with the PHP SDK: getLoginUrl(), then redirect the user to this url, blabla. Works fine if I'm in facebook, and using it as an app.
Problem is if the session is outdated, and I'm not looking this on facebook, this redirecting gets annoying, also: very unprofessional in my opinion...

Thanks in advance!

**SOLVED**: here's the solution for my specific problem:

It took me 1 change of line in the code, which is the following:
`$canvaseurl = ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "https://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/") ? "https://apps.facebook.com/APPNAME/": "https://MYWEBPAGE.hu/app/";`

So I simply redirect to the url, where the user came from.
Pretty simple. :)

Comment: Have you tried with the JavaScript SDK?
You can check if the user is connected with FB.getLoginStatus (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and if not, you can log him in with FB.login (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/). All of this can happen without page refresh/redirect.

Comment: No, didn't think of it.
But the JS-login'll call a pop-up, won't it? And that's just no good. :/ Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the person authorizes the application, you will be able to use either the iframe or the website, just so long as you don't force it to go back to the application page. I have used the Facebook PHP SDK and noticed that if you enter the actual location that is loading into the iframe it will stay on that page outside of the `apps.facebook.com`. However this is dependant on the settings you use. Try experimenting with it and see if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out some things, then report back! :)

Comment: This is just what I noticed when I was messing with it, however you can change the system variables depending on where the page is being loaded. I personally use one version for the iframe app, which I have as a subdomain, and the actual domain as site. This allows for me to keep the themes separate from one another all while using git to manage the core files, only difference is that I change the default template based on location.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I managed to do it, also edited the question so my solution can be found faster.
Thanks again. ^^

Comment: No problem at all just glad to help :)